# Display div list of products when click of 1 products category (and close other div)

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a list of products category that I take from mysql dbb with unique id.
When I click on one product category, I would like to display the list of products for this category and close the other (if one div was open before).
But I don't know how can I do that.

**PHP**:

```
<?php
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {";
$result0 = mysql_query("select * from $table order by idcat");
while ($r0 = mysql_fetch_array($result0)) {
    $idcat_jquery = $r0['idcat'];
    echo '$(\'#lienmenu_'.$idcat_jquery.'\').click(function() {
        $(\'#display_product_info'\').hide('.idcat.');
        $(\'#display_product_info'\').show(' . idcat . ');
        });';
}

echo ' });';
echo '</script>';

$result1 = mysql_query("select * from $table order by idcat");
while ($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $cat = $r1['cat'];
    $idcat = $r1['idcat'];
    echo '<input value="' . $cat . '" id="idcat" class="submit" type="submit"/>';
}
?>
<div id="display_product_info" style="display:none;">
<?php
$result1 = mysql_query("select * from $table2 where idcat='$idcat' order by  productname");
while ($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $productname = $r1['productname'];
    $idproduct = $r1['idproduct'];
    echo '' . $productname . '<BR>';
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using same div for displaying your category products or different DIV?

Comment: I would like to have different div for each category product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set some CSS unique class for active DIV which holds the category products,

When you open another category product remove the active unique CSS class and assign that unique CSS to your new category -> products DIV container.

**EDIT:**

If you are maintaining your category->products with unique DIV {id} then it is easy to manage your active DIV.

You can read all the DIV and apply inactive CSS class (with hide option) for all DIVs and apply active CSS class (with show option).

**Sample:**

```
<div id="container">    
     <div id="cat1"> </div>    
     <div id="cat2"> </div>    
     <div id="cat3"> </div>    
    <div id="cat4"> </div> 
</div>

$("div#container > div").each(function(){
    var element_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#"+element_id).hide();    
});
```

Which cateogry -> products you want to show get that DIV id and:

```
$("#Category_DIV_ID").show();
```

Comment: Thank you ! Could you tell me in jquery what can I do that ? I'm not a "professional of jquery code" :)

Answer (score 0):

Add class:

```
$('#display_product_info').addClass("active");
```

Remove class:

```
$('#display_product_info').removeClass("active");
```

Then give that class some style with `css`.